# Unexpected behaviour with borderless windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I have written a MCVE of a program that is able to identify the attached monitors to a computer, work out their position in the WPF coordinate system, and display identifier windows on the monitor. This works great when the windows are not borderless (not `WindowStyle.None`). It looks a bit like this.

[image]

On the screenshot, the identifier windows look like they are different sizes, but they are the same size in the WPF coordinate system, it is just my primary monitor is set to a scale of 250% and my secondary monitor is only 100%.

The code for laying out the windows is a simple function that, depending on the value of `decorated`, either shows an decorated or borderless window.

```
foreach (Monitor monitor in MonitorUtility.GetMonitors())
{
    Point point = monitor.WpfCoordinateRelativeToTopLeft(10, 10);
    Window tempWindow = new IdentifierWindow(monitor.Number)
    {
        Left = point.X,
        Top = point.Y,
        Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
        Topmost = true,
        Owner = this,
        ShowInTaskbar = false,
        WindowStyle = decorated ? WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow : WindowStyle.None,
        ResizeMode = decorated ? ResizeMode.CanResize : ResizeMode.NoResize
    };
    tempWindow.Show();
    identifierWindows.Add(tempWindow);
}
```

However, when the windows are borderless, strange things happen.

When the application launching the windows is on my main monitor, the result is that the `1` window is in the right place and the right size, but the `2` window does not appear (even though the is a debug bar there).

[image]

When the application launching the windows is on my secondary monitor, the `2` window is positioned correctly and the right size and the `1` window is positioned correctly, but is actually the same pixel size as the `2` window and not the same WPF coordinate size.

[image]

What is even more strange is when I use Visual Studio to inspect where the elements should be using the layout adorner, it highlights the correct size and position for the window every time with a blue translucent highlight. The windows are just not shown there. (Left side of image is when the window launcher is on my primary monitor and right side of image is when the window launcher is on my secondary monitor.)

[image]

---

**Complete MCVE Code**

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="McveMultipleScreensWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="300">
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Click="ShowDecorated_Click" Content="Works" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
        <Button Click="ShowUndecorated_Click" Content="Doesn't work" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
        <Button Click="Hide_Click" Content="Close Windows" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

There is a lot, but it is mostly the code for working out where the monitors are and structs to support the external functions. All this can be collapsed in Visual Studio by the region tags and the code that matters most is at the top.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace McveMultipleScreensWpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

        private readonly List<Window> identifierWindows = new List<Window>();

        private void ShowWindows(bool decorated)
        {
            foreach (Monitor monitor in MonitorUtility.GetMonitors())
            {
                Point point = monitor.WpfCoordinateRelativeToTopLeft(10, 10);
                Window tempWindow = new Window
                {
                    Left = point.X,
                    Top = point.Y,
                    Width = 400,
                    Height = 400,
                    Background = Brushes.Red,
                    Owner = this,
                    WindowStyle = decorated ? WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow : WindowStyle.None,
                    ResizeMode = decorated ? ResizeMode.CanResize : ResizeMode.NoResize
                };
                tempWindow.Show();
                identifierWindows.Add(tempWindow);
            }
        }

        private void CloseWindows()
        {
            foreach (Window window in identifierWindows)
            {
                window.Close();
            }
            identifierWindows.Clear();
        }

        private void ShowDecorated_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ShowWindows(true);
        private void ShowUndecorated_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ShowWindows(false);
        private void Hide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => CloseWindows();
    }

    #region Code required to work out monitor size and position

    internal static class MonitorUtility
    {
        private delegate bool MonitorEnumDelegate(IntPtr monitorHandle,
            IntPtr displayDeviceContextHandle,
            ref Rect monitorSize,
            IntPtr callbackData);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr displayDeviceContextHandle,
            IntPtr clipArea,
            MonitorEnumDelegate callback,
            IntPtr callbackData);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor,
            ref MonitorInformationStruct monitorInformationStruct);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName,
            int modeNum,
            ref DeviceModeStruct deviceMode);

        internal static IEnumerable<Monitor> GetMonitors()
        {
            List<Monitor> monitors = new List<Monitor>();

            EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, delegate (IntPtr monitorHandle, IntPtr displayDeviceContextHandle, ref Rect monitorSize, IntPtr callbackData)
            {
                MonitorInformationStruct monitorInfo = new MonitorInformationStruct();
                // Has to be set before it is used so GetMonitorInfo knows what it is dealing with
                monitorInfo.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(monitorInfo);
                GetMonitorInfo(monitorHandle, ref monitorInfo);

                DeviceModeStruct deviceMode = new DeviceModeStruct();
                EnumDisplaySettings(monitorInfo.DeviceName, -1, ref deviceMode);
                monitors.Add(new Monitor(monitorInfo, deviceMode));

                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);

            return monitors;
        }
    }

    internal class Monitor
    {
        private readonly DeviceModeStruct deviceMode;
        private readonly double dpiScale;

        internal Monitor(MonitorInformationStruct monitorInfo,
            DeviceModeStruct deviceMode)
        {
            this.deviceMode = deviceMode;
            dpiScale = (double)deviceMode.dmPelsWidth /
                       (monitorInfo.Monitor.Right - monitorInfo.Monitor.Left) *
                       ((int)typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("Dpi", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null) / 96.0);
        }

        internal Point WpfCoordinateRelativeToTopLeft(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate)
        {
            return new Point(xCoordinate + deviceMode.fields.Position.x / dpiScale,
                yCoordinate + deviceMode.fields.Position.y / dpiScale);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Code needed for C++ methods

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct MonitorInformationStruct
    {
        private const int DEVICE_NAME_MAX_SIZE = 32;

        internal int Size;
        internal RectangleStruct Monitor;
        internal RectangleStruct WorkArea;
        internal int IsPrimaryMonitor;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = DEVICE_NAME_MAX_SIZE)]
        internal string DeviceName;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RectangleStruct
    {
        internal int Left;
        internal int Top;
        internal int Right;
        internal int Bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DeviceModeStruct
    {
        private const int STRING_SIZE = 32;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = STRING_SIZE)]
        internal string dmDeviceName;
        internal ushort dmSpecVersion;
        internal ushort dmDriverVersion;
        internal ushort dmSize;
        internal ushort dmDriverExtra;
        internal uint dmFields;
        internal DeviceModeUnionOne fields;
        internal short dmColor;
        internal short dmDuplex;
        internal short dmYResolution;
        internal short dmTTOption;
        internal short dmCollate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = STRING_SIZE)]
        internal string dmFormName;
        internal ushort dmLogPixels;
        internal uint dmBitsPerPel;
        internal uint dmPelsWidth;
        internal uint dmPelsHeight;
        internal DeviceModeUnionTwo FlagsNup;
        internal uint dmDisplayFrequency;
        internal uint dmICMMethod;
        internal uint dmICMIntent;
        internal uint dmMediaType;
        internal uint dmDitherType;
        internal uint dmReserved1;
        internal uint dmReserved2;
        internal uint dmPanningWidth;
        internal uint dmPanningHeight;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DeviceModeUnionOne
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal PrinterOnlyFields Printer;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal PointStruct Position;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal DisplayOnlyFields Display;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DeviceModeUnionTwo
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal uint dmDisplayFlags;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal uint dmNup;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct PrinterOnlyFields
    {
        internal short dmOrientation;
        internal short dmPaperSize;
        internal short dmPaperLength;
        internal short dmPaperWidth;
        internal short dmScale;
        internal short dmCopies;
        internal short dmDefaultSource;
        internal short dmPrintQuality;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct PointStruct
    {
        internal int x;
        internal int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DisplayOnlyFields
    {
        internal PointStruct dmPosition;
        internal uint dmDisplayOrientation;
        internal uint dmDisplayFixedOutput;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You should really remove all code that is not needed to reproduce the problem. Your question has way too much code! **M** is MCVE stand for minimal.

Comment: @Phil1970 You are absolutely right. I have minified it. However, the structs at the end are required as they are equivalent to the typedefs required for the code to work in other languages. It is just C# does not have access to this information so I had to write it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this was caused by both `WindowStyle` being set to `WindowStyle.None` and `ResizeMode` being set to `ResizeMode.NoResize`. I'm not entirely sure why this breaks it, but when both are set, it does. When only one (or neither) of them are set, the size and positioning works as expected.

The way around this is to use a WindowChrome component in the popup window. For example,

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome
        UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"
        CaptionHeight="0" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

`UseAeroCaptionButtons` disables the hit test on the caption buttons (Minimize, Maximize, and Close). `CaptionHeight="0"` hides the bar at the top of the window. When combined, is essentially equivalent to `WindowStyle.None` but it does not break when combined with `ResizeMode.NoResize`.

Putting the attribute `ResizeMode="NoResize"` disables the resize.

---

**Complete example**

*IdentityWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="McveMultipleScreensWpf.IdentityWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="IdentityWindow" Height="400" Width="400"
        Background="Red"
        Topmost="True"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome
            UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"
            CaptionHeight="0" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Content -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*IdentityWindow.xaml.cs*

```
namespace McveMultipleScreensWpf
{
    public partial class IdentityWindow
    {
        public IdentityWindow() => InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="McveMultipleScreensWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="300">
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Click="Show_Click" Content="Open Windows" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
        <Button Click="Hide_Click" Content="Close Windows" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace McveMultipleScreensWpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

        private readonly List<Window> identifierWindows = new List<Window>();

        private void ShowWindows()
        {
            foreach (Monitor monitor in MonitorUtility.GetMonitors())
            {
                Point point = monitor.WpfCoordinateRelativeToTopLeft(10, 10);
                Window tempWindow = new IdentityWindow
                {
                    Left = point.X,
                    Top = point.Y,
                    Owner = this
                };

                tempWindow.Show();
                identifierWindows.Add(tempWindow);
            }
        }

        private void CloseWindows()
        {
            foreach (Window window in identifierWindows)
            {
                window.Close();
            }
            identifierWindows.Clear();
        }

        private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ShowWindows();
        private void Hide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => CloseWindows();
    }

    #region Code required to work out monitor size and position

    internal static class MonitorUtility
    {
        private delegate bool MonitorEnumDelegate(IntPtr monitorHandle,
            IntPtr displayDeviceContextHandle,
            ref Rect monitorSize,
            IntPtr callbackData);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr displayDeviceContextHandle,
            IntPtr clipArea,
            MonitorEnumDelegate callback,
            IntPtr callbackData);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor,
            ref MonitorInformationStruct monitorInformationStruct);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName,
            int modeNum,
            ref DeviceModeStruct deviceMode);

        internal static IEnumerable<Monitor> GetMonitors()
        {
            List<Monitor> monitors = new List<Monitor>();

            EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, delegate (IntPtr monitorHandle, IntPtr displayDeviceContextHandle, ref Rect monitorSize, IntPtr callbackData)
            {
                MonitorInformationStruct monitorInfo = new MonitorInformationStruct();
                // Has to be set before it is used so GetMonitorInfo knows what it is dealing with
                monitorInfo.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(monitorInfo);
                GetMonitorInfo(monitorHandle, ref monitorInfo);

                DeviceModeStruct deviceMode = new DeviceModeStruct();
                EnumDisplaySettings(monitorInfo.DeviceName, -1, ref deviceMode);
                monitors.Add(new Monitor(monitorInfo, deviceMode));

                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);

            return monitors;
        }
    }

    internal class Monitor
    {
        private readonly DeviceModeStruct deviceMode;
        private readonly double dpiScale;

        internal Monitor(MonitorInformationStruct monitorInfo,
            DeviceModeStruct deviceMode)
        {
            this.deviceMode = deviceMode;
            dpiScale = (double)deviceMode.dmPelsWidth /
                       (monitorInfo.Monitor.Right - monitorInfo.Monitor.Left) *
                       ((int)typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("Dpi", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null) / 96.0);
        }

        internal Point WpfCoordinateRelativeToTopLeft(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate)
        {
            return new Point(xCoordinate + deviceMode.fields.Position.x / dpiScale,
                yCoordinate + deviceMode.fields.Position.y / dpiScale);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Code needed for C++ methods

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct MonitorInformationStruct
    {
        private const int DEVICE_NAME_MAX_SIZE = 32;

        internal int Size;
        internal RectangleStruct Monitor;
        internal RectangleStruct WorkArea;
        internal int IsPrimaryMonitor;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = DEVICE_NAME_MAX_SIZE)]
        internal string DeviceName;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RectangleStruct
    {
        internal int Left;
        internal int Top;
        internal int Right;
        internal int Bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DeviceModeStruct
    {
        private const int STRING_SIZE = 32;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = STRING_SIZE)]
        internal string dmDeviceName;
        internal ushort dmSpecVersion;
        internal ushort dmDriverVersion;
        internal ushort dmSize;
        internal ushort dmDriverExtra;
        internal uint dmFields;
        internal DeviceModeUnionOne fields;
        internal short dmColor;
        internal short dmDuplex;
        internal short dmYResolution;
        internal short dmTTOption;
        internal short dmCollate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = STRING_SIZE)]
        internal string dmFormName;
        internal ushort dmLogPixels;
        internal uint dmBitsPerPel;
        internal uint dmPelsWidth;
        internal uint dmPelsHeight;
        internal DeviceModeUnionTwo FlagsNup;
        internal uint dmDisplayFrequency;
        internal uint dmICMMethod;
        internal uint dmICMIntent;
        internal uint dmMediaType;
        internal uint dmDitherType;
        internal uint dmReserved1;
        internal uint dmReserved2;
        internal uint dmPanningWidth;
        internal uint dmPanningHeight;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DeviceModeUnionOne
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal PrinterOnlyFields Printer;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal PointStruct Position;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal DisplayOnlyFields Display;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DeviceModeUnionTwo
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal uint dmDisplayFlags;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal uint dmNup;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct PrinterOnlyFields
    {
        internal short dmOrientation;
        internal short dmPaperSize;
        internal short dmPaperLength;
        internal short dmPaperWidth;
        internal short dmScale;
        internal short dmCopies;
        internal short dmDefaultSource;
        internal short dmPrintQuality;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct PointStruct
    {
        internal int x;
        internal int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct DisplayOnlyFields
    {
        internal PointStruct dmPosition;
        internal uint dmDisplayOrientation;
        internal uint dmDisplayFixedOutput;
    }

    #endregion
}
```